# Access to grouping variable from within d_ply

Tags: r, plyr

I just discovered the great `plyr` package and am taking it for a spin.

A question I have is the following: is there some way to access the grouping variables from within `d_ply`?

Say I have a dataframe `df` with columns `x,y,z`, and I would like to plot for each `z` the values `x` versus `y`. If I do the following:

```
plotxy = function(df, ...) {plot(df$x, df$y, ...)}
d_ply(df, .(z), plotxy(df, main=.(z)))
```

then the titles that show up on the plots are all "z", and not the values of the z variable. Is there a way to access those values from within `d_ply`?

EDIT: As @Justin pointed out, the above formulation is wrong because I am passing the whole of `df` to `plotxy`. Hence the line

```
d_ply(df, .(z), plotxy(df, main=.(z)))
```

should be

```
d_ply(df, .(z), plotxy, main=.(z))
```

in order to make sense in terms of my original question (I guess that's also what @joran was hinting at).

However, I realized something else. Even though `df` gets sliced along `z` by `d_ply`, the sub-dataframe that the function receives still has a `z` column -- simply with always the same value. Hence the problem can apparently be solved as follows:

```
plotxy = function(df, ...) {plot(df$x, df$y, main=df$z[1])}
d_ply(df, .(z), plotxy)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the only problem you have with this code? I'm worried it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @joran : Thank you for worrying. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a meeting. Justin covered my concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By way of example, I'll expand on Joran's concern.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=letters[1:10])
```

lets use your function and see what we get without plyr:

```
plotxy(df, main=.(z))
```

versus the maybe more expected(?):

```
plotxy(df, main=df$z)
```

However, in you code, you are splitting your data frame on z then sending the *whole data.frame df* to your function again.  Instead you could make a wrapper function:

```
d_ply(df, .(z), function(ply.df) plotxy(ply.df, main=unique(ply.df$z)))
```

This way the `plotxy` function is only seeing the smaller split data.frame ply.df that you pass through the wrapper function.

Comment: Am I right in saying the OP is basically doing:
     `plotxy = function(df) {for (i in z) plot(df$x, df$y)}`
which is `plot(x,y)` as many times as `length(z`)?

Comment: Yes. However, I assumed that was not the intent.  Instead the intent would be to: `plot(df$x[df$z==i], df$y[df$z==i], main=i)`.  (and your function would need to be `for (i in unique(df$z)) ...`